# Как сделать клики по окну которое сейчас не используется?

Tags: python

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы произошел клик по окну, но мышь не передвинулась и желательно чтобы окно могло быть свернутым. Я слышал что тут может помочь win32gui, но так и не разобрался как это реализовать. Очень желательна реализация на питоне.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Двойной мгновенный прыжок мышки. Прыгаешь в другое окно (не передвигаешь - а именно прыгаешь), после прыгаешь обратно.

На счёт на win32gui - я не знаю, а уточнить не могу (заблокированы вопросы, репы нет), из названия скорее всего следует,что WIN - 32. Возможно это значит, что библиотека на 32-ух битные системы?

P. S. Если мой ответ не помог - напишите в комментарии, сразу же удалю.